# Search several words in a MSSQL varchar field with EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My project is using ASP.Net Core 1.1, EF Core and a SQL Server database.

I have an array of strings which should be searched in a text field (actually the field is a list of tags, and the array an array of tags).

The full scenario:

- On my server side (.Net Core), I have an array of tags {'tag2', 'tag4'}.
- Each place is stored in SQL Server with a list of tags separated with coma 'tag1,tag2,tag3'.
- I would like to get the 20 closest places that match at least one tag.

I have thought about passing a datatable as parameter to a SQL function having a custom type parameter, however datatable type is not yet included in .Net Core until v2.

The C# code in the entity DbContext class would be something like:

```
decimal lat=2.0, lng=3.0; float maxRadius=50000;
var tags = new Array<string>(){"tag1", "tag2"};

var places = await this.Set<Place>()
               .FromSql("SELECT * FROM GetPlaces(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)", maxResults, lat, lng, maxRadius, tags).ToListAsync();
```

(Of course unfortunately passing tags like this doesn't work)

The SQL function would be something like this:

```
WITH Results as (
    SELECT p.Id, p.Name
            , ([geography]::Point(@lat,@lng,(4326))).STDistance(Coordinates)) AS Distance
    FROM Places p
    INNER JOIN ValsToSearch v 
        ON p.Tags LIKE '%'+v.Val+'%'
    WHERE Distance < @distance
)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(20) * FROM Results 
ORDER BY Distance
```

This one does not seem very efficient to me as it multiplies the fields with the join then distincts them, but I don't know if it is possible to make it better.

I would like to get the most efficient query to do something similar to this.

Any help/ideas? :) 
Loading everything in memory is not an option as there are like 200k lines in the database (and in some area it may be quite dense)

Another option would be in the c# code, however as coordinates do not exist in the NetCore version 1.1, I am not sure it would be translated into SQL correctly (with `CONTAINS` or `LIKE` queries):

```
var places = await (from p in this.Set<Place>()
         .FromSql("SELECT * FROM GetClosestPlaces(@p0, @p1, @p2)", lat, lng, maxRadius)
         where (from t in tags where p.Tags.Contains(t) select t).Any()
         select p).Take(maxResults).ToListAsync();
```

with the SQL function that would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetClosestPlaces]
    (@lat decimal,@lng decimal,@maxRadius float=50000)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
    SELECT * FROM Places 
        WHERE ([geography]::Point(@lat,@lng,(4326)))
            .STDistance(([geography]::Point([Latitude],[Longitude],(4326)))) 
            < @maxDistance
```

Any recommendation?

The objective would be on SQL side the less resource consuming, and on both sides, the less time consuming (service that should be give very fast answers as it may be called several times for the same query).

---

"At this time" I haven't found any nice solution in database. So I pre-filter the database data with my other filters (distance), and then apply the text filter in memory.
It's much more efficient: 500ms for the SQL solution vs 100-150ms for the linq solution.

Comment: can 'SQL Server Full-Text Indexing' be used in this scenario?

Comment: I guess so, but I have never used yet :) 
It is an Azure DB (limited by DTUs).
A 'tag' is up to varchar(20) and the Tags field is varchar(255)

Comment: You can enable full text search in SQL Azure, across multiple fields.  However afaik you cannot directly query the index in EF.  You can however execute a custom query string easily enough that utilises the full text index.

Comment: Is it possible to parametrise the CONTAINS words?
ex: `WHERE CONTAINS(Tags, @prm1+' OR '+@prm2)`

This syntax looks weird - not very clean...
The only solution I found is to add several 'contains' constraints with 1 parameter.